# OpenGL: read texture into image in memory with arbitrary row stride/padding

Tags: opengl

I want to read a texture into memory, where the destination image can have arbitrary padding at the end of each row. To clarify, the padding is the same for all rows.

I know that textures are read with glGetTexImage. I have also looked into glPixelStorei, but this can only add padding, which respects boundary alignment with a very limited options.

Is there a way to do that in OpenGL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer the questions myself since I found out that I have been reading the documentation of OpenGL ES 2.0, which has a severe lack in functionality in regard to glPixelStore. But anyway, you can use this function with GL_PACK_ROW_LENGTH to specify the displacement between two consecutive rows.